# How I Can Convert SQL query to Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can I convert the following query into a laravel eloquent query?

```
SELECT demand_costings.pr_number as Demand_Costing,work_types.work_types,
                 SUM(demand_costings.pr_quantity_in_pcs) as Total  
FROM demand_costings
     INNER JOIN work_types
ON demand_costings.worktype_id=work_types.id
GROUP BY work_types.work_types;
```

Comment: uh, before swarms of downvoters come.. could you tell us what you have tried? the [docs is pretty explanatory](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries)..

Comment: You sure you want to covert this query? Because the query is **invalid** and **abusing** MySQL's GROUP BY "feature" and can cause **invalid** results for the column `Demand_Costing` because it's not in the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel's `DB` facade:

```
$data = DB::table('table_name')
    ->select(DB::raw('emand_costings.pr_number as Demand_Costing,work_types.work_types,SUM(demand_costings.pr_quantity_in_pcs) as Total FROM demand_costings INNER JOIN work_types ON demand_costings.worktype_id=work_types.id'))
    ->groupBy('work_types')
    ->get();
```

Comment: This query is **invalid** and **abusing** MySQL's GROUP BY "feature" and can cause **invalid** results for the column Demand_Costing because it's not in the GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DB::table('demand_costings')
                ->select([
                    'pr_number as Demand_Costing',
                    'work_types',
                    'SUM(pr_quantity_in_pcs) as Total'
                    ])
                ->join('work_types', 'demand_costings.worktype_id', '=', 'work_types.id')
                ->groupBy('work_types.work_types')
                ->get();
```